# Github action failing react test, running locally

Tags: reactjs, testing, github-actions

My test suites were running fine in GH actions (and locally). Suddently they are not running anymore (still running locally). The problem seems to be async functions timing out for some reason:

```js
Timed out in waitForNextUpdate after 1000ms.
```

My .yml file with the action:

```html
name: Webapp test and build

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ dev ]
    types: [opened, closed]

jobs:
  test_build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.GIT_TOKEN }}
        fetch-depth: 0
      
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'yarn'
        
    - name: Install packages
      run: yarn install
        
    - name: Run Tests
      run: yarn test
```

Once more, test running locally on Node 14 and same repo. Any hints or help deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was missing environmental variables in Github actions. Why the tests were originally passing in GH actions is still a mistery...